# How can I calculate the historical volatility of a stock in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, finance

I would like to create some simulated historical options data, and need to calculate historical volatility from historical stock prices. Is there a built in function to do this?  Any formulas?

Comment: idk but searching a bit first result gave http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24811-historical-volatility and I suspect that mathworks may have a lot of other resources about matlab and the problems it can handle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only built-in functions I found were in the [Financial Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/finance/):

- [BLKIMPV](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/finance/blkimpv.html)
- [BLSIMPV](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/finance/blsimpv.html)
- [CHAIKVOLAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/finance/chaikvolat.html)

Other than that, here are some other links that may help:

- [Trading with MATLAB](http://tradingwithmatlab.blogspot.com/2008/06/estimate-historical-volatility.html) blog
- [Historical Volatility](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24811-historical-volatility) by [Josiah Renfree](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/27774) on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) (link from ShinTakezou's comment above)